# How to create a page that lists all the experts(Users with same access permission as author)?

Tags: pages, users

I want to create a page that lists all the experts(Users with same access permission as author).

One solution I could think of is to create a page from the WordPress dashboard (Eg:medical-experts) then create medical-experts.php at the backend that lists all the experts with get_users($medical_expert_custom_args) function.

Please let me know if there is any better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: I think that is a great solution, it's what I would do.....since you can use the $args to limit the results by role, as long as each of your experts has the same role this will work fine and allow you to do some nice custom styling for the page.

Comment: Thank you @Trisha